# Use of undefined constant contacts - assumed 'contacts' error

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I have been working to insert data into a database with laravel. Everything went fine. But know I am stuck with the error: "Use of undefined constant contacts - assumed 'contacts'". I do not know how to fix this.

I have already on the Laracast website to see if I could find an explanation on how to solve this, but I couldn't since the answers were not the once I was looking for. I have also looked in StackOverflow. But there were (again) no answers that could help me fix this the problem. I also have asked a classmate of mine but he also couldn't fix it.

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\contacts;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    /*Haal alle data op uit de contact tabel return een view file*/
    public function index($contact = contacts){

    $Contact = contacts::all();

    return view('contact',compact('contacts'));
}

/*Return een view file*/
public function create(){
    return view('contacts');
}

public function storeContact(){
    /*Maakt nieuwe variabele, wanneer er op de knop wordt geklikt worden er 2 waardes opgehaald.*/

    $contacts = new contacts();

    $contacts->name = request('voornaam');
    $contacts->description = request('bericht');

    $contacts->save();

    return redirect('/contacts');

}
}
```

My view:

```
@extends ('Layout')
@section('title')
    Contact
@endsection

@section('content')
<br>
    <h2>Contact</h2>

    <p>Voor verdere informatie (die u niet op onze website kunt vinden) kunt u ons bereiken op onze email of telefoonnummer:</p>
    <p>Email: Cronensteynfake@gmail.com</p>
    <p>telefoonnummer: 06-11122234</p>
    <br>

    U kunt ook ons contactformulier invullen.
    <br><br>
    <h2>Cronenstyn Contactformulier</h2>
    <form action="" method="post">
    @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Voornaam</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Vnaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Achternaam</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Anaam" placeholder="Achternaam">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Uw email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Wij delen uw email met niemand</small>
  </div>
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Bericht</label>
  <div class="form-group shadow-textarea">
  <textarea class="form-control z-depth-1" id="bericht" rows="3" placeholder="Uw bericht"></textarea>
</div>
  <button onclick="Message()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verzenden</button>
  <script>
      function Message() {
  alert("Uw bericht is met succes verstuurd.");
}
      </script>
</form>
    @endsection
```

My route:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::GET('/home',('CronensteynController@home'));
Route::GET('/nieuws',('CronensteynController@nieuws'));
Route::GET('/galerij',('CronensteynController@gallerij'));
Route::GET('/activiteit',('CronensteynController@activiteit'));
Route::GET('/contact',('CronensteynController@contact'));
Route::GET('/about',('CronensteynController@about'));

Route::get('/beheer', 'PageController@beheer');
Route::get('/create_beheer', 'PageController@Create_beheer');
Route::get('/update_beheer', 'PageController@Update_beheer');
Route::get('/delete_beheer', 'PageController@delete_beheer');

Route::post('/create_beheer', 'CreateBeheerController@store');
Route::post('/contact', 'contactsController@index');
```

Hopefully I have given you enough info and code about the problem.

Greetings,

Parsa_237

Comment: `$contact = contacts` should be `$contact = "contacts"`

Comment: Thx! The error is gone but now I have one that says the class App/contacts cannot be found?

Comment: You are mixing 'contacts' and 'Contacts', see if the model name is 'contacts' or 'Contacts'.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer Sujeet. I have changed the model name and now it works again. Would you like to post this answer not as a comment but an answer so that I can say this question is answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow a convention to avoid errors regarding cases.
Generally models start with a capital letter.

> Always make your model name singular. For model Contact laravel will look the table contacts. 
>   For more information on naming convention you can follow this [link](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions)

Here you are passing `$contact` to index method you don't have to do that.

```
public function index(){
    $Contacts = contacts::all();
    return view('contact',compact('Contacts'));
}
```